# Bulk changing annotation locations in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, annotation

I'm working with a large number of labels that I've converted to annotation (using ArcMap 10.1). All of them need to fit within the parcel borders that they correspond to.

Is there a way to do it all at once or am I stuck going one by one to fit them in the boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you experiment with the [Maplex Labelling Engine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_the_Maplex_Label_Engine/00s80000007m000000/) (part of Core at all license levels at 10.1) there is a chance that you may not need to create annotation.